# Laravel session not working between views

Tags: laravel

Its a laravel 5.2 app. I have these 2 functions:

```
public function page1()
{
        Session::put('test', '1');
        $value = Session::get('test');
        echo 'test: '.$value;
}

public function page2()
{
    $value = Session::get('test');
    echo 'test: '.$value;
}
```

I first go to localhost/page1. And I can see that the page prints:

```
test: 1
```

I then go to localhost/page2

But the page prints:

```
test:
```

So it seems like the sessions are not shared among views. Why? Is this some config issue?

This is route.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'pages'], function()
{
    Route::get('page1', 'AdminController@page1');
    Route::get('page2', 'AdminController@page2');
});
```

Comment: Show `routes.php` file please.

Comment: I added route.php to main description.

Comment: Which session driver are you using?

Comment: I using filesystem. I can see that the session files are saved under storage/frameworks/session

Comment: How are you getting test: test in first route? You should get test: 1

Answer (score 2):

i write same code as you in controller as below :

```
public function page1()
{
      Session::put('test', '1 ');
      $value = Session::get('test');
      echo 'test: '.$value;
}

public function page2()
{
  $value = Session::get('test');
  echo 'test: '.$value;
}
```

and route file is also same :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'pages'], function()
{
    Route::get('page1', 'AdminController@page1');
    Route::get('page2', 'AdminController@page2');
});
```

and it is working properly->
Output:
http://localhost/laravel-5.2/public/pages/page1

```
test: 1
```

http://localhost/laravel-5.2/public/pages/page2

```
test: 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I also have the same code, but its not working. Strange. Must be somewhere else.

Comment: it also strange that. _your_  **output**  is **test:test  and _my_ output** is **test:1**  . the value of session test

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue about session persistence in laravel https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172

If you use `Session::save()` every time when after update session,may be your problem will solved.So your page1 method will be

```
public function page1()
{
    Session::put('test', '1');
    Session::save()
    $value = Session::get('test');
    echo 'test: '.$value;
}
```

Comment: didn't help, still no value at page2 :(